# Creating numbers with "For loop" using matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave, numerical-methods

I'm trying to loop a pattern of numbers using a For loop in matlab / octave
The pattern I'm looking for is
**40,80,160,320,280,200** and then **1 is added to each one** so the pattern would look like this:

```
40,80,160,320,280,200,41,81,161,321,281,201,42,82,162,322,282,202
```

I tried using a for loop below

```
clear all
numL_tmp=[40;80;160;320;280;200]

numL=[numL_tmp];
for ii=1:length(numL_tmp)
    for jj=1:4
        numL=[numL;numL_tmp(ii,1)+jj]
    end
end
```

But I get

```
40,80,160,320,280,200,41,42,81,82,161,162,321,322,281,282,201,202
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem stated, **nested loops are unnecessary**. You could simply do the following:

```
clear all;
numL_tmp=[40;80;160;320;280;200];

numL = numL_tmp;
for ii=1:2
    numL = [numL;numL_tmp+ii];
end

numL
```

This would yield:

```
numL =

    40
    80
   160
   320
   280
   200
    41
    81
   161
   321
   281
   201
    42
    82
   162
   322
   282
   202
```

This works because MATLAB recognizes the piece of code `numL_tmp+ii` as something equivalent to `numL_tmp + ii*ones(size(numL_tmp))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid loops completely:

```
N = 3;
numL = kron(ones(N,1),numL_tmp) + kron((0:N-1)',ones(numel(numL_tmp),1));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are easier ways to do it, but the fundamental problem with your code is that the inner and outer loops in the wrong order. See what happens if you leave your code as is, but simply interchange the order of the two loops:

```
...
numL=[numL_tmp];
for jj=1:4
    for ii=1:length(numL_tmp)
       numL=[numL;numL_tmp(ii,1)+jj]
   end
end
```